# Subclassing UINavigationBar with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm writing an app that gives a user tokens to spend and I want to display the user's current number of tokens in a `UINavigationBar`. What I would like to have is a label with the number of tokens, and an image of a coin in the top right corner of my navigation bar.

I've been searching for ways to customize the `UINavigationBar`, and have found plenty of posts related to adding an image to cover the entire bar, and changing the title. However, I can't find a simple way to do what I want.

I think I need to subclass `UINavigationBar` and add the text/image myself, but being new to **iOS** development and Swift, I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom view contains subviews `UILabel` and `UIImageView` to show the token number and token image. Add it to right bar button item of the navigation controller.

It will look like:

[image]

Below code will create the custom view. Here you can observe that it is a local variable. However, you can manage global variable for custom view or create a whole new class and manage it independently for real-time updates to show token number.

```
// Custom to hold token number and image
let tokenView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:44))
tokenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

// Label to show token number
let tokenLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:60, height:44))
tokenLabel.text = "1234"
tokenLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right

let imageHeight = CGFloat(30)
let marginY = CGFloat((tokenView.frame.size.height / 2) - (imageHeight / 2))

// ImageView to display token image
let tokenImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "coin"))
tokenImage.frame = CGRect(x:70, y:marginY, width:30, height:30)

tokenView.addSubview(tokenLabel)
tokenView.addSubview(tokenImage)

// Add custom view as a right bar button item
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: tokenView)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the current number of tokens you can just set the title. In your view controller:

```
navigationItem.title = '\(numberOfCoins) coins"
```

If you want to do anything more fancy you can set your own title view instead of the standard UILabel:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIView(...) // your custom view
```

To show the coin in the top right corner you'd set the `rightBarButtonItem`:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
  image: UIImage(named:"Coin"),
  style: .Plain,
  target:self,
  action:"tappedCoinButton:")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't think I need to have the button call a function right now but if I do I'll make sure to use this.

Comment: When you create the UIBarButtonItem, the `target` can be nil. Users expect buttons in the corners of navigation or toolbars to do something, though, so I'm not sure it's a good design to just have an image there that doesn't do anything. If you just want a coin next to the number of coins, create a custom titleView and put it in there.